# Twitter bootstrap thumbnail are not side by side

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
      <header>
        <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
             <div class="thumbnail">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                       </a>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="caption">
                     <h3 class="thumbnail-label"><a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php get_template_part('templates/entry-meta'); ?>
                     <div class="entry-summary">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                      </div>
      </header>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </article>
```

im having trouble getting these to align side by side. All they do is stack on top of each other and i cant seem to get them to be side by side.

Here is what its suppose to look like http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be closing the `<header>` tag too early. Try this mark-up instead:

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <!-- Your thumbnail code goes here. -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</article>
```

**Note:** If you are using this code inside a loop then that would explain why the thumbnails are stacking.

Comment: im using them on the static front page..is there a workaround if i am using a loop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<article>` tag contains element that's looped, you're looping too much content. Your markup should read:

```
{outside_element}
    {loop}
        {looped_element}
    {/loop}
{/outside_element}
```

running this through 3 iterations will give you:

```
{outside_element}
    {looped_element}
    {looped_element}
    {looped_element}        
{/outside_element}
```

where now you get:

```
{outside_element}
    {looped_element}        
{/outside_element}
{outside_element}
    {looped_element}        
{/outside_element}
{outside_element}
    {looped_element}        
{/outside_element}
```